# redirect using javascript or jquery in greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, greasemonkey

i want to redirect from the first link to the other using javascript or jquery in greasemonkey

```
       http://*.tumblr.com/post/*/*
       http://$1.tumblr.com/image/$2
```

Comment: Is not a duplicate it is a brand new one  
i need the redirector to be case sensitive to the formula of the i/p to get a definitive o/p

also as you see i want to implement the first and second variable $1,2 and ignore the 3rd

so both examples you mention which i was already read them are in complete in my opinion

but if you can put the answer using these examples which i could not at all 

then please By all means 

and Thank You For Your help

Comment: None of those details are in your question! And it's still not clear what you are trying to do exactly.  Nevertheless, all manner of redirects and regex location swaps have already been asked and answered.  This question is a duplicate as well as unclear.  The best match requires clarification on your part.

Comment: I don't see this as a duplicate of the question linked to, as this asks for a very different thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex

```
/^http:\/\/(.*).twitter.com\/post\/(.*)\/(.*)/g
```

Like this

```
var regexp = new RegExp(/^http:\/\/(.*).twitter.com\/post\/(.*)\/(.*)/g);
var results = regexp.exec(window.location.href);
```

To create your array, then you can

```
if(results){
    window.location="http://"+results[1]+".twitter.com/image/"+results[2]+"/"+results[3];
}
```

To redirect

[Live Version](http://projects.bygph.com/jsproblem4.html)